# CR10S Pro V2 Screen not working after replacing the hotend extruder

Tags: creality-cr-10

Recently my hotend extruder got stripped out so I bought a new one and went to replace it, after finishing, my screen wouldn't turn on and it is no longer connecting to my PC. The filament sensors light is on, the BLTouch sensor is not on and all the fans are working, from pictures I've seen there is supposed to be a light on the motherboard, but, that I don't see on my motherboard, all pictures I've taken are with the printer plugged in and on.

[image: Transfer Board]
[image: Tranfer Board]
[image: Mother Board]
[image: Screen Board]
[image: This Thing]
[image: Fuse Box]